# Contains matching in Google tag manager for element classes

Tags: google-tag-manager

Below is the configuration of a trigger for firing certain tag:

[image]

while debugging this trigger is getting triggered despite, the element that's clicked do not contain "**t-dont-need-prescription**" instead it contains "**t-need-prescription**".

Below is the screenshot from preview mode:
[image]

Clearly i am missing something here. **How is "t-donot-need-prescription" contains "t-need-prescription" hold true?**

Comment: Looks like you're still using legacy GTM V1 variables. Can you at least switch to the V2 auto-event variables, like `Page URL` and `Click Classes`?

Comment: @nyuen how is this comment relevant to my question? You think this will solve the issue? If so please add some more description that'll be really helpful

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Your first image shows that GTM is trying to match 'contains' "t-dont-need-prescription" whereas the debug is trying to match 'contains' "t-need-prescription". In your screenshot from preview mode, t-need-prescription is in t-dont-need-prescription. As in t-don  \\ t-need-prescription

Comment: @sdhaus am feeling like dumbest person on the planet. I did not see that. Thanks, now i see why its getting true.